# Upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 failed

Tags: 11.04, installation, upgrade, virtualbox, dpkg

Today Ubuntu asked me to upgrade to 11.04. The installation went completely fine until right at the end when the following packages failed:

```
install-info
ubuntu-standard
```

The installer hung so I had to shut it down manually. Ubuntu still works fine but it says that the upgrade didn't work properly so I am hesitant to restart it until I have resolved the problem in case I can't get back in.

I am running Ubuntu inside the latest version of Virtual Box and was previously running version 10.10.

I have tried installing install-info manually with apt-get but I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception: [#<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>]
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:842:in `block in <class:Autotest>': undefined method `backtrace' for [#<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>]:Array (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in `[]'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in `block in hook'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in `each'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in `any?'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in `hook'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:344:in `rescue in run'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:320:in `run'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:241:in `run'
    from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/bin/autotest:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/ruby/bin/autotest:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/ruby/bin/autotest:19:in `<main>'
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of info:
 info depends on install-info; however:
  Package install-info is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing info (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-standard:
 ubuntu-standard depends on info; however:
  Package info is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-standard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                        Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
 info
 ubuntu-standard
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas on what I should try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured out the problem. In my /etc/environment file I had a line for RSPEC beneath the PATH variable. Deleting this solved the problem.